# VirtualBox, Ubuntu and screen resolution

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

The host system is an iMAC:

```
macOS Mojave
Version 10.14.5
iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015)
Processor 4 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Graphics AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4 GB
```

VirtualBox:

```
Version: 6.08 r130520 (Qt5.6.3)
VirtualBox 6.0.8 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
```

The virtual machine is Ubuntu 14.04.  In the virtual machine I have installed the guest additions:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

I restarted the VM after installing this.  The problem is that in the System Settings / Screen Display I still only see a resolution of 640 x 480 (4:3) with no option to select a higher resolution.

What haven't I done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the other posts I found a solution that works:

- In the Ubuntu VM, open a terminal and type:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
  ```
- With the VM running, use the Devices menu option which is available in the host operating system.
- Select the option "Insert Guest Additions CD Image..."
- Back in the Ubuntu VM, open a terminal and type:

  ```
  cd /media/<username>/VBox_GAs_6.0.8
  sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
  ```

Once this has been done, shutdown and restart the VM.

Now everything is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you still experience problems with setting resolution after setting resolution resizing to 'None' or 'Automatic' in VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Display and mounting GuestAdditions execute following command in guest's terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

It worked for me - guest was Ubuntu 18.04